# WheelListener для увеличения размера кисти через JFrame (Paint через SWING)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Драсте !
Задался таким вопросом, как можно при помощи "addWheelListener" увеличть при прокрутке колесика вверх или вниз размер "кисти" в данном Paint'e ?

Код:

```
public int mousex = 100;
private int mousey = 100;
private boolean isMousePressed = false;

private Color[] palette = { Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.YELLOW,
        Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN };

private int currentColor = 0;

public MyPaint() {
    Timer timer = new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            repaint();
        }

    }

    );
    timer.start();

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            mousex = e.getX();
            mousey = e.getY();

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            mousex = e.getX();
            mousey = e.getY();

        }

    });

    addWheelListener(new WheelListener() {

        @Override

    }

    addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < palette.length; i++) {
                if (e.getY() <= 100 && e.getX() >= 100 * i && e.getY() <= 100 * (i + 1)) {
                    currentColor = i;
                }
            }

        }


        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            isMousePressed = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            isMousePressed = false;

        }

    });

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < palette.length; i++) {
        gr.setColor(palette[i]);
        gr.fillRect(100 * i, 0, 100, 100);
    }

    if (isMousePressed){
    gr.setColor(palette[currentColor]);
    gr.fillOval(mousex - 1, mousey - 1, 25, 25);
    }
}
```

Comment: И в чем конкретно проблема? В коде вы определили слушатель, который ничего не делает.